# SQLite cursor returns older columns on upgrade

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I am upgrading the DB, version number of the DB gets updated, but when queries are fired, for the first 2 times older cursor columns are returned.

For ex
Number of columns before migration: 16 
Expected number of columns after migration: 21

However, after migrations are run
DB version number is updated, but number of columns is 16 for the first query
Then it gets updated to 21 in the next query or app restart.

Does any one know why this might be happening?

The following is the mock code for the same

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DbHelper helper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
        helper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable (names TEXT, co TEXT)");
        Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable", null);
        Log.d("rajas", "Count - " + c1.getColumnCount());
        c1.close();
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN pass TEXT");
        Cursor c2 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable", null);
        Log.d("rajas", "Count  - " + c2.getColumnCount());
    }
    class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "dbdbb", null, 1);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code the count before and after migration will remain the same as 2.

Comment: Please share the piece of your problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

**This appears to be a bug.**

There are a number of get arounds you can :-

- get the total (unhidden) column count by using the [**table_info**](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) (or **table_xinfo** to include hidden columns) PRAGMA.

  - Note that this method looks at the table not a Cursor and therefore it's use should be used with care.
- or close and re-open the database.

  - the disadvantage of this method is that opening the database is relatively costly resource wise.
- SELECT specific columns

For Example consider :-

```
    helper = new DbHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable (names TEXT, co TEXT)");
    Cursor c1 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable", null);
    Log.d("rajas", "Count - " + c1.getColumnCount() + " Alt count = " + (c1.getColumnNames()).length);
    c1.close();
    Cursor ti = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(mytable);",null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(ti);

    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN pass TEXT");

    Cursor c2 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable", null);
    Log.d("rajas", "Count  - " + c2.getColumnCount() + " Alt count = " + (c2.getColumnNames()).length);
    ti = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(mytable);",null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(ti);
    ti.close();

    Cursor c3 = database.rawQuery("SELECT names,co,pass FROM mytable", null);
    Log.d("rajas", "Count  - " + c3.getColumnCount() + " Alt count = " + (c3.getColumnNames()).length);
    ti = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(mytable);",null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(ti);
    c3.close();
    ti.close();

    database.close();
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c4 = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable", null);
    Log.d("rajas", "Count  - " + c4.getColumnCount() + " Alt count = " + (c4.getColumnNames()).length);
    c4.close();
```

This results in :-

```
2019-12-03 07:48:23.484 D/rajas: Count - 2 Alt count = 2
2019-12-03 07:48:23.485 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5df21a1
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    cid=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    name=names
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    cid=1
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    name=co
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.486 I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-12-03 07:48:23.491 D/rajas: Count  - 2 Alt count = 2
2019-12-03 07:48:23.491 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@fc68fc6
2019-12-03 07:48:23.491 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.491 I/System.out:    cid=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.491 I/System.out:    name=names
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    cid=1
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    name=co
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    cid=2
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    name=pass
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.492 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.493 I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-12-03 07:48:23.493 D/rajas: Count  - 3 Alt count = 3
2019-12-03 07:48:23.493 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@7dbb87
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    cid=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    name=names
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    cid=1
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    name=co
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.494 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out:    cid=2
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out:    name=pass
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out:    type=TEXT
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out:    notnull=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out:    dflt_value=null
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out:    pk=0
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out: }
2019-12-03 07:48:23.495 I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-12-03 07:48:23.498 D/rajas: Count  - 3 Alt count = 3
```